# Promise вывод понятной ошибки пользователю

Tags: javascript, promise

Есть вот такой код:

```
function get_json(url) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        $$.post(url,resolve,reject);
    }).then(JSON.parse);
}

get_json('auth.php').then(function (data) {
    alert(data.name+', вы авторизовались!');
}, function(e) {
    alert('Ошибка авторизации: '+e);
});
```

Если сервер вернёт кривой json, то JSON.parse вернёт ошибку и получится:
`Ошибка авторизации: SyntaxError: Unexpected token e in JSON at position 0`
И пользователю не будет понятно в чём проблема.

Как вывести эту ошибку в консоль, а пользователю при ошибки JSON вывести:
`Ошибка авторизации: сервер передал некорректный ответ, повторите попытку.`

Comment: очевидно, нужно проверить что пришло в `e` и на основании проверки вывести ту или иную строку

Comment: @Grundy вы прилагаете это реализовать так!? https://jsfiddle.net/8kp65zkt/

Comment: @Mr_Epic а почему на сервере не высылать не кривой json а нормальный? либо сразу сообщение об ошибке такое какое вам нужно показывать?

Comment: @Mr_Epic, это слишком в лоб решение, поменяется ответ, который не будет начинаться с `e` и все сломается опять :) Но суть верная: проверить что пришло и на основании этого сформировать сообщение

Comment: @Moonvvell на счёт второго, потому что ошибка может быть не только в JSON, например может быть сервер не доступен или ещё что

Comment: @Grundy, а более гуманного решения нету?

Comment: @Mr_Epic, например? В чем измеряется гуманность решения?

Comment: @Grundy ну например так: если ошибка идёт именно от JSON.parse, то выводить ту ошибку, то есть без проверки текста ошибки.

Comment: @Mr_Epic, оберни JSON.parse в try...catch и обрабатывай ошибку в конкретном месте